# Jquery CSS not working on div from Post

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page that gets a div using jquery's post method.   I then try to apply css to the divs and it doesn't work.  when i use jquery to apply css on divs that are already on the page, it works for them.

Jquery:

```
$('#next').click(function() {

    $.post('getquestions.php', {number: number}, function(result){

        $('#questionArea').html(result);
    });

$('.quest').css( "border", "13px solid red" );  //this doesn't work

});
```

Echoed out from getquestions.php (this is working correctly):

```
    echo "<div id='question" . $question_number . "' class='quest'>";
```

Comment: use `$('#questionArea').find('.quest').css( "border", "13px solid red" );`

Comment: just tried it.  didnt work :(

Comment: this seems to be already an issue that was answered. Did you try moving the CSS definitions to the css file as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751124/jquery-apply-css-on-ajax-content

Comment: @Bala what do you mean by move it to the css file?  i checked that link but i still dont understand

Comment: i meant to move the style definitions to a CSS file instead of placing it in the html file in a <style> tag. once in a CSS file add it to the page via <link> tag. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Bala thanks.  i tried to implement that but the reason i used jquery in the first place was so that i could have a variable selector. if I import my css file, i dont think i can modify the selector

Answer (score 1):

it's because your div with class `quest` is not available when you execute the jquery's `css` function. Since `$.post` is an async function, the div is only added to the DOM by `$('#questionArea').html(result);` when `$.post`'s callback is executed, so you should do the css call there.

should be like this:

```
$('#next').click(function() {

    $.post('getquestions.php', {number: number}, function(result){

        $('#questionArea').html(result);
        // the div is just added
        $('.quest').css( "border", "13px solid red" );
    });
    // the div is not added to DOM yet since $.post has not finished fetching the result

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `$(document).find('.quest')`

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to add the css in `.done()` after post request? Like

```
$.post( "example.php", function() {

    alert( "success" );

})

.done(function() {

    alert( "second success" );

});
```

Or

```
var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

// Put the results in a div

posting.done(function( data ) {

var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );

$( "#result" ).empty().append( content );

});
```

Source : [jQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)